# Device specific Graphics for Universal iOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-universal-app, xcasset

I've configured my app as Universal in Target/General/DeploymentInfo

Is it ok to make device specific assets in the xcassets file for iPhone and iPad, **even though the app as a whole is Universal**? It seems to work, but I'm worried if there is some catch.

Background:
I plan to add 2X and 3X versions of some assets in the 2x and 3x boxes in the iPhone section, and 2X and 4X versions in the 1x and 2x boxes in the iPad part. I use a capital X to describe the scale of my assets.

Note, that the 2X asset will be used twice. Both in iPhone and iPad. Maybe there's a way around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this at all.

Where I work, we've done this for our games: different asset bundles are downloaded depending on the device the game is running on.

This allows us to adjust for older hardware, like iPad 2.

Comment: Will only the needed assets for the specific device be downloaded? I.e. only ONE png per texture even though there are multiple pngs in the Image Set? In that case the doubling of the 2X png is a bit awkward, but it won't make the download bigger.

Comment: Well, ours is a Unity project. So we have a High Definition bundle with textures at higher resolution than the Standard Definition bundle.